# OpenCL header file difficulty

Tags: opencl, header-files

So I am trying to set up a way to easily develop OpenCL programs which turned out to be the hardest part of learning this language so far. I include CL/cl.h in my source files but I keep getting compiler errors that the headers don't exist. When I change the include to only be cl.h it works but every program I have seen so far uses CL/cl.h so I am assuming it is some sort of macro to allow either file. Any ideas how I can get around this or possible fixes?

This is my makefile

PROJ=ocl_intro

CC=mingw32-g++

CFLAGS=-std=c99 -Wall

LIB=-lOpenCL

ifdef INTELOCLSDKROOT

```
INC_DIRS="$(INTELOCLSDKROOT)include\CL"

LIB_DIRS="$(INTELOCLSDKROOT)lib\x86
```

endif

$(PROJ): $(PROJ).cpp

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ -I$(INC_DIRS) -L$(LIB_DIRS) $(LIB)
```

.PHONY: clean

clean:

```
rm $(PROJ).exe
```

Comment: You need to tell your compiler where the header files and the library files are. What is your IDE?

Comment: I'm using mingw. I have all the paths correct. Like I said, if I change the include statement to #include <cl.h> instead of #include <CL/cl.h> it can find the files. I just see everyone else's code saying the second notation. I even changed to the C++ wrapper but that library makes an indirect call to CL/cl.h which it can't find. Ugh, headaches

Comment: What are your mingw command line arguments???! My guess is you are passing the include/CL folder of your OpenCL headers and not the include/ folder as required. We can't help you until you give actual data, unless you find answers such as "it might be" or "I speculate that" useful.

Comment: I've spent days trying to get someone else's program to compile. I just want to start parallel programming and learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
INC_DIRS="$(INTELOCLSDKROOT)include\CL"
```

To:

```
INC_DIRS="$(INTELOCLSDKROOT)include"
```

You are looking for "CL/cl.h", obviously it's not going to find a folder  called "CL" inside "include\CL", since you're already giving the "CL" folder as a search path. As is now, you're essentially asking the compiler to find "\include\CL\CL\cl.h", clearly the compiler will fail since this file does not exist.

You are meant to simply provide the path to the "include" folder - conventions will do the rest.

Comment: Ugh, thanks. That worked. Finally I can start. Any suggestions for a solid, difficult first program to write in parallel? Trying to think of something possible but still going to make me work.

Comment: @MrWolvwxyz Difficult? You could try writing a path tracer, smallpt style, on the GPU. It does require quite a bit of work and will introduce a lot of concepts.

Comment: Thank you so much, like I said I have tried Eclipse, VS, and OpenCL studio. Days wasted just trying to get a way to compile .cl kernels

Comment: I have one more question. I have g++ finding all the libraries, but now I am having the problem that when g++ compiles the code included in cl.hpp it can't declare any function that uses the size_t type. I changed my makefile to be std=-c++0x instead of c99, could this have done it? I included stddef.h but this didn't seem the help the problem. Do I need to go into every cl header and include this library or could it have been the standard the compiler was using?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that you can't use cl and std namespaces.